# How do I extract the values from this data using bash and awk?

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I grepped these, how do I extract the values?

```
...
cavity_2mgl_wt_strip57001.out: Total cavity volume (A3)               : (  1.240E+01) 
cavity_2mgl_wt_strip58001.out: Total cavity volume (A3)               : (  2.408E+00) 
cavity_2mgl_wt_strip60001.out: Total cavity volume (A3)               : (  4.935E+00) 
cavity_2mgl_wt_strip61001.out: Total cavity volume (A3)               : (  1.319E+00) 
cavity_2mgl_wt_strip63001.out: Total cavity volume (A3)               : (  1.532E-01) 
cavity_2mgl_wt_strip64001.out: Total cavity volume (A3)               : (  1.137E+01) 
...
```

and I need the index # in the filename in bold:

```
cavity_2mgl_wt_strip76001.out: Total cavity volume (A3)               : (  1.276E+01)
```

and I need the number in the parenthesis:

```
cavity_2mgl_wt_strip76001.out: Total cavity volume (A3)               : (  1.276E+01)
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more err specific?

Comment: I want to create a file that contains the numerical value from the file name. mached with the value in the parenthesis.

Answer (score 6):

```
$ ..<commands>.. | awk -F"[:)(]" '{gsub(".*strip|.out","",$1);print $1,$(NF-1)}' 
57001   1.240E+01
58001   2.408E+00
60001   4.935E+00
61001   1.319E+00
63001   1.532E-01
64001   1.137E+01
```

or if your grepped values are already in a file

```
$ awk -F"[:)(]" '{gsub(".*strip|.out","",$1);print $1,$(NF-1)}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's/.*strip\(.*\).out.*(\([^:].*\))/\1 \2/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure is a lot shorter in perl than awk. I don't know how flexible your format is; I put in a few wildcards just in case:

```
perl -ne 'if ($_ =~ /cavity_[0-9]+mgl_wt_strip([0-9]+)\.out:[^:]+: *\( *([0-9]+\.[0-9]+E[+-][0-9]+)\)/) {print "$1 $2\n"}' in.txt > out.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using sed?

```
sed -e 's/.*strip\([^.]*\).*( *\([^ )]*\) *).*/\1 \2/' infile > outfile
```

The first capture is of the part of the line between "strip" and the next dot.
Then the line until the last opening bracket is skipped.
The second capture is of the number (with any leading and trailing space removed) between the last pair of brackets.

Answer (score 1):

In pure bash:

```
while read line; do
   tmp="${line#*strip}"; index="${tmp%.out*}"
   tmp="${line##*(}";    value="${tmp%)*}"
   printf "%s:%s\n" "$index" "$value"
done < file
```